# Remove HTML Codes from quill

Tags: javascript, html, quill

I want to remove the html codes from my QUILL Editor. Is there an option or way to remove the HTML code when saving the content of the quill?

Here is my code:

```
function initialize_quill(){
var limit = 250;

var options = {
    theme: 'snow'
};

var collectionnotequill = new Quill('#collection-note-quill', options);

collectionnotequill.on('text-change', function () {
    if (collectionnotequill.getLength() > limit) {
        collectionnotequill.deleteText(limit, collectionnotequill.getLength());
    }
});
}
```

Comment: https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#gettext `.getText()`